# How do I configure Azure Databricks to use VSTS for Source Control

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, databricks, continuous-delivery

I have recently began using Azure Databricks and comparing to Jupyter Notebooks running on HDInsight.  I have searched around and read documentation trying to learn how to have ADBricks use VSTS git for source control.  However, I have not found a solution that works.

I have found instructions for using other git providers, but I want to be clear that is not an option for this use-case so please refrain from those types of responses.

HDInsight has similar limitations, but I could work around via ssh/rsync, and that was fine because I was deploying to the remote server, same way a build would, and able to blue/green deployments and the like same way a build would do.

For ADBricks, the cluster-on-demand is amazing, but there is an assumption that you're developing in Notebooks "on the cluster" and effectively you're in Continuous Delivery mode.  This is just fine with me (except for the less-than-adequate, high-latency notebook development), but I still need to automate getting code to VSTS periodically to save state/backup like a good coder should :).

Comment: You say you haven't found a solution that works. What solutions *have* you tried, and what *didn't* work with them?

Comment: There was no approach I found to try since ADBricks doesn’t support VSTS.  I looked for a way to script an upload with sync/ssh in Azure but all I found was instructions for AWS.  If I’m missing something obvious then I would be grateful for a link to documentation so I can learn.

Answer (score 3):

Typically for full CI/CD in Azure Databricks we use the workspace API to pull and push whole notebooks or directories from Databricks to a user's local machine or a build server. https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/workspace.html

Databricks also has a CLI that leverages the workspace API for easier, higher-level commands: https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dev-tools/databricks-cli.html

The workflow for this looks something like this:
[image]

Here is a blog from Databricks that goes into more detail:https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/continuous-integration-continuous-delivery-databricks.html

Comment: Request first class VSTS support here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909463-azure-databricks/suggestions/33716101-git-integration-with-vsts

Answer (score 2):

For now, there has no such connections between Azure Databricks and VSTS git repo.

But there has an user voice [Add Git support for Visual Studio Team Services for Azure databricks](http://feedback.databricks.com/forums/263785-product-feedback/suggestions/33735778-add-git-support-for-visual-studio-team-services-fo) which suggests the connections, you can vote and follow up there. And you can describe your details requirement there (such as version control notebooks, integrate with VSTS CI and CD etc).

Comment: Thanks Marina,  I hope they do add support.  I'd like to see MSFT begin to require a Disaster Recovery capability from their tenant applications.  VSTS integration seems table stakes to me for an 1st class Azure tenant.

Comment: The feature has been reviewing by databricks team, but it will take a period to apply it for release.

Answer (score 2):

There is now built in support for Azure DevOps, aka VSTS:

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/notebooks/azure-devops-services-version-control.html